# req.body throws an empty {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am using `body-parser` but it's not working and I don't know what the problem is.

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());      
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', redirection, function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('index', {title: 'Home'});
});

router.get('/country', function(req, res, next) {
    // CountryName

    res.render('country',
   { 
     title: 'Home',
     mainJS: 'main.js',
     //country: req.body.countries
    });

    console.log(req.body)
});

function redirection(req, res){
    if (req.url == '/'){
        res.redirect('/country');
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

In this code it throws {}

What is the problem?

Comment: where do you call your `console.log()`

Comment: Is the `console.log(req.body)` the only thing that you have in your index.js? Because you're supposed to have a router in it that you export using `module.exports` I assume, since you're saying `var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');`, and then `app.use('/', indexRouter')`

Comment: I used ```console.log(req.body)``` in router ```('/')```

Comment: yea index.js have router codes not only console.log

Comment: Could you show the entire index.js then? And also the way you're testing this (sending the request).

Comment: What does the request look like that is arriving at the server?  Is it a POST? Does it have a body?  Is it properly encoded to match the content-type in the header.  There's not enough info here shown for us to help further other than wild guesses.  So, please show us the code sending the request and show us the route handler where the problem lies.

Comment: I edited index.js in the post, please review it

Comment: @MuhammadSharaqi jfriend is asking for the client code

Answer (score 0):

Your server only receives a request body in [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) (or PUT or PATCH) operations, not in [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) operations. You don't have `router.post()` in your sample code, so it seems you are not handling POSTs.  Therefore, no `req.body`.

You can find your `https://example.com/?query=parameters&query2=parameters` at `req.params.query` and `req.params.query2`.

You can't use the location bar of a browser to do a POST: they from a form posts or [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) / [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) operations.